# Python Twisted – How to connect via proxy using HostnameEndpoint and ClientService?

Tags: python, web-services, proxy, twisted

I’m updating code that used to use the old api for twisted (WebSocketClientFactory and connectWS()) to connect to a web service. To better support ipv6 I have now updated to use the new api using HostnameEndpoint and ClientService.

To support TLS I use wrapClientTLS(). Is there anything similar to use for proxy?

Before I could use the proxy settings in WebSocketClientFactory but it does not seem to work any more. And I so far, can not find anything similar in the doc for endpoint.

How do I connect via http proxy when I use HostnameEndpoint and ClientService?

Here I try to set it with WebSocketClientFactory. I get an exception with “Connection was aborted locally using ITCPTransport.abortConnection.”.

```
`    
    proxy = {'host': proxy_config['host'], 'port': int(proxy_config['port'])}
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory(url, protocols=['my_protocol'], proxy=proxy)
   
    if use_ssl:
        wrapped = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, server, port)
        context_factory = ssl.optionsForClientTLS(hostname=server)
        endpoint = wrapClientTLS(context_factory, wrapped)
    else:
        endpoint = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, server, port)

    my_service = ClientService(endpoint, factory)
    my_service.startService()
    reactor.run()`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. What is important with the endpoint api is to remember that it will do the socket connection. Therefor it should connect to the proxy server and not the web server. The factory will then negotiate with the proxy for the connection to the web server. One additional note is that the communication with the proxy is without SSL/TLS, so that should also be taken care of.

My new source code look like this

```
proxy_cfg = {'host': proxy_host, 'port': int(proxy_port)}
factory = WebSocketClientFactory(url, protocols=['my_protocol'],
                                 proxy=proxy_cfg)

if proxy_cfg:
    endpoint_server = proxy_cfg["host"]
    endpoint_port = proxy_cfg["port"]
else:
    endpoint_server = server
    endpoint_port = port

if use_ssl and not proxy_cfg:
    wrapped = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, endpoint_server, endpoint_port)
    context_factory = ssl.optionsForClientTLS(hostname=server)
    endpoint = wrapClientTLS(context_factory, wrapped)
else:
    endpoint = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, endpoint_server, endpoint_port)

my_service = ClientService(endpoint, factory)
my_service.startService()
reactor.run()
```